# How and Where to SET and Check group_concat_max_len

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For this query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users  (
columns.......
)
```

do I put `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 999999` before or after creating the tables? And how can I check if it is actually `SET` to `999999` using a query like
`SHOW group_concat_max_len` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **`SET group_concat_max_len`** before executing **`SELECT`** query.

Comment: But what if i want to `SET` the the `length` for every `GROUP_CONCAT` to `99999` for all my future queries? do i have to put it in every `SELECT` query?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/346866/set-group-concat-max-len-permanently-mysql-config  Check this one out.

Comment: i guess it is named `my.ini` in xampp, checked it, Seems like it didn't `SET` it, Do i have to put it manually Or there is a possible way without using it inside an `SELECT` in the previous query?

Comment: @CaliburVictorious Exactly..!!

Comment: So what is the different between `GLOBAL` and `SESSION` while in `SELECT` query?